# What happens when HashMap or HashSet maximum capacity is reached?

Tags: java, collections, size, hashmap, overflow

Just a few minutes back I answered a question asking about the "*Maximum possible size of HashMap in Java*". As I have always read, ***HashMap is a growable data-structure. It's size is only limited by the JVM memory size.*** Hence I thought that there is no hard limit to its size and answered accordingly. (The same is applicable to HashSet as well.)

But someone corrected me saying that since the **size()** method of HashMap returns an **int**, there *is* a limit on its size. A perfectly correct point. I just tried to test it on my local but failed, I need more than 8GB memory to insert more than 2,147,483,647 integers in the HashMap, which I don't have.

My questions were:

- What happens when we try to insert 2,147,483,647 + 1 element in the
  HashMap/HashSet?
- Is there an error thrown?
- If yes, which error? If not what happens to the HashMap/HashSet, its already
  existing elements and the new element?

If someone is blessed with access to a machine with say 16GB memory, you can try it out practically. :)

Comment: Belongs on MapOverflow.com

Comment: You don't need 16 GB RAM. Just get a 64-bit version of Windows and create a pagefile for the rest to test.

Comment: Have you looked into the HashMap's source code? You'll then quickly see why this is capped by the size of an integer.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: Thanks for the comment, I will have a look. But I was trying to figure out what will happen if we insert more than integer-limit number of items in it.

Comment: @Kerrek: I do not understand that - just another SE spinoff?

Comment: @home you know: when the map overflows. haha.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: haha, got it :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The underlying capacity of the array has to be a power of 2 (which is limited to 2^30) When this size is reached the load factor is effectively ignored and array stops growing.

At this point the rate of collisions increases.

Given the hashCode() only has 32-bits it wouldn't make sense to grow much big that this in any case.

```
/**
 * Rehashes the contents of this map into a new array with a
 * larger capacity.  This method is called automatically when the
 * number of keys in this map reaches its threshold.
 *
 * If current capacity is MAXIMUM_CAPACITY, this method does not
 * resize the map, but sets threshold to Integer.MAX_VALUE.
 * This has the effect of preventing future calls.
 *
 * @param newCapacity the new capacity, MUST be a power of two;
 *        must be greater than current capacity unless current
 *        capacity is MAXIMUM_CAPACITY (in which case value
 *        is irrelevant).
 */
void resize(int newCapacity) {
    Entry[] oldTable = table;
    int oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
    if (oldCapacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return;
    }

    Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
    transfer(newTable);
    table = newTable;
    threshold = (int)(newCapacity * loadFactor);
}
```

When the size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE it overflows.

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is limited to 2^30, I mean where does 30 come from? And why it cannot become 31, 32...?

Comment: Arrays are limited to a size to a signed 32-bit number.  This is a historical restriction which is hard to fix to allow signed long sizes unfortunately. The maximum signed `int` value is 2^31-1. However the size of the array has to be a power of two (due to the way HashMap works) and this is one too few, so the largest power 2 it can be is 2^30.  Given hashCode has only 2^32 possible values, having much more than this is rather pointless in any case. ;)

Comment: I work with larger collections including hash maps and use a 64-bit size/length and 64-bit hashCode for these reasons.

Comment: so you mean you can store more than 2,147,483,647 items in the hashmap? if yes, how do you do that? i would like to know.

Comment: You can store values in a HashMap, but the size will be wrong.  However what I use is a map which uses a hash, or a hash map in the generic sense.  The problem you have with such a hash map is the shear size of it.  Say you want to store 256 bytes for the key, the value and any over head.  That's 512 GB for a single collection, more than the size of your memory and possible more than the free space of one drive. (Using SSDs can be up to 1000x faster than using a HDD for random access)

Comment: To do this I use memory mapped byte buffers.  Many of them, because unfortunately they suffer from the same `int` size limit that arrays do.  If you want to use powers of two for sizes, you have the same 2^30 limit for each memory mapping.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "This method is called automatically when the
 * number of keys in this map reaches its threshold." Who decides when the number of keys reaches threshold and what is the calculation for threshold ?

Comment: @Geek the threshold is the "load factor" passed in the constructor `*` the capacity. See the last line of `resize()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 for the folow up.